# JDBC connection to databricks server is failing in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, sql

I have working JDBC connection to data bricks server in Java code.

I'm trying to make similar connection in my JMeter project (tried with apache-jmeter-5.3 and apache-jmeter-5.4.3) using same connection details.

I put SparkJDBC42.jar in JMeter lib (downloaded from https://databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download).

To connect I've used `com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver` class.

In Database Url using  `jdbc:spark://adb-...`

I've tried:

- using UID and PWD inside Url
- using UID and PWD in Username and Password fields
- using UID and PWD in Connection Properties.

No matter what I do, I keep getting error:

```
"Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.simba.spark.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL ..."
```

I followed instructions from this post last response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66913893/how-can-i-connect-jmeter-with-databricks-spark-cluster

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should contain more comprehensive information regarding the error.
2. Also you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the JDBC components by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="debug" />
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the change up.

   JMeter log file should contain sufficient amount of troubleshooting information in order to guess the failure reason
3. Given you have working Java code you can re-use it in JMeter via:

   - [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
   - [JUnit Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request)
   - [Java Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)
   - Or [write your own plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)

   whatever is the easiest to implement and support